# Почему Graphql отдает undefined если все в console.log есть данные?

Tags: node.js, graphql

есть Resolver в котороместь методом Query. Требуется искать ресторан по ид
и если к примеру мы вставляем такой код, Все отлчно работает

```
Restaurant: async(parent, args) => {
      return await Restaurant.findOne({_id: args.id})
    }
```

Однако если я добавлю методы populate и execPopulate я на фронте получаю undefined

```
Restaurant: async(parent, args) => {
      const items = await Restaurant.findOne({_id: args.id})
      const populatedItems = await items.populate('kinds').execPopulate()
      return populatedItems
    }
```

Если же делать console.log(populatedItems) есть объект с нужными данными, и метод populate так же хорошо отработал. насколько я заметил из более 2 часов тестов, GraphqL перестает рабатать когда в дело вступает метод populate

Comment: Попробуйте `return Restaurant.findById(args.id).populate('kinds');` в одной конструкции

Comment: @entithat , пробовал, к сожалению безуспешно

Comment: @entithat тогда Return работает но populate без execPopulate не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ошибку, дело в том что в Type я определил что получаю только ID и поэтому когда я получал объект kinds вместо id была ошибка. Надо было исправить в Type и query